# Active/active pacemaker?

Tags: centos7, high-availability, pacemaker

> Blockquote

"I want to create a HA cluster with two nodes.So,does anyone can give me the configuration of two nodes with pacemaker and corosync?I want to use pacemaker with active/active mode.Thank for watching my question!"

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer below document in Redhat 7. I think it will be helpful for you.

[High-Availability](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/High_Availability_Add-On_Administration/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-High_Availability_Add-On_Administration-en-US.pdf)